# write HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write below html code in JavaScript.
So I try this way. But Didnt work. Any Idea?

```
var liHtml = "<div class="slider"><div class="slide"><img src='" + MyImage + "'" +  "/></div></div><div class="accordion"><div class="header">" + MyHeader + "</div><div class="content">"+ MyContent+ "</div></div>";
```

HTML COde

```
<div id="slidorion" class="slidorion">
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide"><img src="img/boxing.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="img/athletics.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="img/basketball.jpg" /></div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <div class="header">Muhammad Ali</div>
    <div class="content"><-- CONTENT GOES HERE --></div>
    <div class="header">Usain Bolt</div>
    <div class="content"><-- CONTENT GOES HERE --></div>
    <div class="header">Michael Jordan</div>
    <div class="content"><-- CONTENT GOES HERE --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lookout for quotes!!!

Comment: Escape the double quotes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: Look at this part: `"<div class="slider"`. How should JavaScript know that the string is **not** supposed to end at the first `"`? (i.e. `"<div class="`)

Answer (score 2):

Consider mixing single-quotes and double-quotes and use them consistently (i.e. single quotes for attributes and double-quotes for defining your strings). By doing this, it will make it much easier to avoid getting into a nasty "quote-hell" scenario:

```
var liHtml = "<div class='slider'><div class='slide'><img src='" + MyImage + "'" + "/></div></div><div class='accordion'><div class='header'>" + MyHeader + "</div><div class='content'>" + MyContent + "</div></div>";
```

Answer (score -1):

I think just this would work

```
document.write(liHtml);
```